# How can i iterate over the following using Javascript to count the number of teams?

Tags: javascript, iteration

```
var data = {
    "name": "nba",
        "conference": [
        {
            "name": "Eastern",
            "divisions": [
                {
                    "name": "Atlantic",
                    "teams": [
                        {
                            "location": "Brooklyn",
                            "name": "Nets"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Boston",
                            "name": "Celtics"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "New York",
                            "name": "Knicks"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Philadelphia",
                            "name": "76ers"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Toronto",
                            "name": "Raptors"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Central",
                    "teams": [
                        {
                            "location": "Chicago",
                            "name": "Bulls"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Cleveland",
                            "name": "Cavaliers"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Detroit",
                            "name": "Pistons"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Indiana",
                            "name": "Pacers"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Milwaukee",
                            "name": "Bucks"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Southeast",
                    "teams": [
                        {
                            "location": "Atlanta",
                            "name": "Hawks"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Charlotte",
                            "name": "Bobcats"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Miami",
                            "name": "Heat"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Orlando",
                            "name": "Magic"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Washington",
                            "name": "Wizards"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Western",
            "divisions": [
                {
                    "name": "Northwest",
                    "teams": [
                        {
                            "location": "Denver",
                            "name": "Nuggets"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Minnesota",
                            "name": "Timberwolves"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Oklahoma City",
                            "name": "Thunder"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Portland",
                            "name": "Trailblazers"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Utah",
                            "name": "Jazz"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Pacific",
                    "teams": [
                        {
                            "location": "Golden State",
                            "name": "Warriors"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Los Angeles",
                            "name": "Clippers"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Los Angeles",
                            "name": "Lakers"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Phoenix",
                            "name": "Suns"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Sacramento",
                            "name": "Kings"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Southwest",
                    "teams": [
                        {
                            "location": "Dallas",
                            "name": "Mavericks"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Houston",
                            "name": "Rockets"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "Memphis",
                            "name": "Grizzlies"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "New Orleans",
                            "name": "Pelicans"
                        },
                        {
                            "location": "San Antonio",
                            "name": "Spurs"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Maybe `JSON.stringify(data).match(/location/ig).length` but if you write some code you'll get a real answer.

Comment: @RobG: That is brillant.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen - brilliant, yes, but brittle. I'd be concerned about what happens when there's another item added about where the division's playoffs (or something like that, I don't know a thing about sports) are taking place. Then you've got another "location", which throws off the counts. Sometimes being explicit is better than being slick. But my hat is still off to RobG for such a slick idea.

Comment: @Stephen: Not brilliant, [brillant](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=brillant). I know it's fragile, trust me, I've dealt with these computer machines before.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Whoa, that was a serious typo. Whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Matti said, use some loops:

```
var i = 0,
  j = 0,
  k = 0,
  conference,
  division,
  teamCount = 0,
  teams = [];

for(i = 0; i < data.conference.length; i++) {
  conference = data.conference[i];
  for(j = 0; j < conference.divisions.length; j++) {
    division = conference.divisions[j];
    for(k = 0; k < division.teams.length; k++) {
      teamCount += 1;
      teams.push(division.teams[k].name);
    }
  }
}

console.log(teamCount);
console.log(teams.join(','));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AMQ8W/2/

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to tackle this.

```
teamCount = 0;
for(var i = 0, l = data.conference.length; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(division);
    var division = data.conference[i];
    for(var ti = 0, tl = division.divisions.length; ti < tl; ti++) {
        teamCount += division.divisions[ti].teams.length;
    }
}
```

Simple, straightforward. But you're likely going to want to expand upon it in the future, and then after a while you've ended up with three levels of loops. Which is a lot of fun for some folks. I prefer legibility. This code is a touch slower, but it is arguably easier to read.

```
function countTeams (data) {

    var teamCount = 0;

    function conferenceIterator (conferences) {
        for(var i = 0, l = conferences.length; i < l; i++) {
            divisionIterator(conferences[i].divisions);
        }
    }

    function divisionIterator (division) {
        for(var i = 0, l = division.length; i < l; i++) {
            teamCount += division[i].teams.length;
        }
    }
    conferenceIterator (data.conference);
    return teamCount;
}

console.log(countTeams(data));
```

Each of the functions has its own scope, so there's no concerns about accidentally using "i" twice or anything like that. And it's just generally a bit easier to read - you can use more verbose function names to describe what each is doing.